# What would be the procedure if I wish to code entanglement swapping?

Tags: programming, entanglement-swapping

Most of the methods that I have seen in various papers all take single examples and then proceed to manually perform swapping by re-writing the states on a different basis and then performing a measurement to swap entanglement.

Examples: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Tutorials_(Rioux)/Quantum_Teleportation/357%3A_An_Entanglement_Swapping_Protocol

Or entanglement is spoken about very briefly, such as in:
Horodecki, R., Horodecki, P., Horodecki, M., & Horodecki, K. (2009). Quantum entanglement. Reviews of Modern Physics, 81(2), 865–942. - Page 12

I wish to code entanglement swapping for some arbitrary state of 4 qubits, of which A-B and C-D are entangled. I wish to perform the swapping leaving A-D entangled. How would I go about doing the same? I was unable to find any detailed resources on swapping or a generalized entanglement swapping procedure anywhere.

Comment: Is entanglement swapping the same as quantum teleportation?

Comment: @Mauricio entanglement swapping is teleportation of qubits that are entangled.

Comment: Check this https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html

Comment: @Mauricio thanks, but that doesn't solve the question I asked. It would be helpful if I wanted to code it using qiskit, but it does not help with the procedure that I would have to follow for entanglement swapping if I wanted to perform symbolic computation.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is in this paper :
[Fusion-based quantum computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.09310)

Look at the "Bell fusion" in Fig 2. Basically you measure $X_BX_C$ and $Z_B Z_C$
and that leaves $q_A q_D$ entangled.